# interface change - envelope gone

Tags: discussion

the envelope that went colored when I had replies, is now a down arrow.

what would indicate when/if I have new replies?

I suppose i'll find out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange logo contains your replies network-wide, and will light up when there are:

- new answers to your questions
- new comments on your questions or answers
- comment replies that directly address @you

You can also look on your user page, on the responses tab at the top.

Comment: looks like a good change, but would've been smoother if along with it had been a link to a thread about it and the newer look.